# How to add label and back button to tap gesture viewcontroller in swift

Tags: swift, label, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am using this pod [GSImageViewerController](https://github.com/wxxsw/GSImageViewerController) for tap gesture.. **but i am getting separate view in image with black screen.... but here i need in that black screen back button and name label.. how to add please let me know..**

**code for tap gesture:**

```
import UIKit
import GSImageViewerController
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tapImage: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    tapImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    tapImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}

@objc func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
  //  let tappedImage = tapGestureRecognizer.view as! UIImageView
    let imageInfo = GSImageInfo(image: tapImage.image!, imageMode: .aspectFit)
    let transitionInfo = GSTransitionInfo(fromView: tapImage)
    
    let imageViewer    = GSImageViewerController(imageInfo: imageInfo, transitionInfo: transitionInfo)

    present(imageViewer, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

in black image view how to add back button and label.. please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the pod directly download [GSImageViewerController.swift](https://github.com/wxxsw/GSImageViewerController/tree/master/GSImageViewerController) and add it to your project. Then you can modify the **GSImageViewerController** class as per your requirement.

Comment: okay, here how and where to add label and button in the view